# Сбросить счётчик голосов за закрытие вопроса

Tags: поддержка, модерация

На [примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743983/how-to-change-callback-buttons-size-in-telegram-bot-on-c) сегодняшнего вопроса, который был практически закрыт (отдано 4 голоса за закрытие с формулировкой "Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке", после чего автор поправил свой вопрос и закрытия прекратились).

Меня беспокоит то, что в текущей ситуации если кто-нибудь подаст ([в течение ближайших 4 дней](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away)) голос за закрытие с любой формулировкой — то вопрос будет немедленно закрыт, хотя по-хорошему голосование нужно начинать заново.

В принципе, похожая ситуация может быть и с другими вопросами, которые болтаются в очереди проверки. Например, на вопросе пара голосов за закрытие как "слишком общий", но видно, что в текущей редакции вопрос уже поправлен.

Вопрос который меня интересует: могут ли модераторы сбрасывать счётчик голосов на закрытии?

Понимаю, что альтернатива очевидна: можно закрыть вопрос, добив его любой причиной, а потом начать повторное голосование за переоткрытие. Однако, не хочется ущемлять автора, который провёл работу и сам поправил вопрос (бывает, что приходится переводить кому-то другому).

Comment: да, модераторы могут :-) по крайней мере @Nicolas точно может :)

Comment: @Grundy, не могут.

Comment: @Qwertiy, беда-беда огорчение. Но мне кажется Nicolas точно что-то такое делал

Answer (score 2):

Сбрасывать голоса за закрытие модераторы не могут.

Наличие в вопросе проблем с качеством при первичном появлении вопроса часто решает его судьбу не лучшим для него образом. Это надо иметь в виду, и потому стараться как можно лучше сформулировать вопрос перед его публикацией. Плохо подготовленный вопрос получает голоса за закрытые и минусы, которые редко когда полностью откатываются назад. Чтобы отозвать тот или иной голос, нужна причина, такой причиной обычно является редактирование сообщения. Однако, участник, отдавший голос на сообщении, не получает какого-либо автоматического уведомления о правке сообщения. И таким образом, вероятность того, что голос будет отозван, крайне мала. Другое дело, что голоса за закрытие (по сравнению с голосами «за» и «против») имеют тенденцию к протуханию, и недобитый вопрос, будучи отредактирован, еще может вернуться в нормальное русло.